# What does "WAITING FOR SENS" mean at bootup

Tags: windows-10, reboot

Running **Windows 10**. it used to work fine. It started a few months ago - After an update and reboot, it appears to hang in the BIOS. A cold boot always works.

This time there was a message `Waiting for SENS`.  What problem does this point to ?

I did google for it.  Most of the hits are for servers and when Windows is already running, and the fixes are to be executed at that point in time.

The closest one [At microsoft](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d546af27-f5b0-4d9b-a935-715e862e68dc/server-2012r2-and-the-dreaded-quotplease-wait-for-the-system-event-notification-service) is on a server in 2014.  The answer hints at teething problems in the new **System Event Notification Service**.  Eight years later, this can't be a teething issue, and I am not running a server.

I shall try again, tomorrow, with a different browser and account.

Comment: Have you performed an independent search using the terms you've provided? A substantial number of results appear to provide options to resolve this problem.

Comment: Yes, they are referring to when windows is already running. Mine is at reboot. So I cant try the remedies, such as looking the task manager etc.

Comment: When does the message show up? If it's at the system firmware then it's unlikely to be related to the Windows service even if the name happens to be the same. Can you open the firmware's boot menu (F8 etc) and check what boot choices are there?